# SQLAlchemy: Relationship with ForeignKey consisting of two columns

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy for my Flask application, and I wish to connect two tables, where the relationship should be made on two ForeignKey that are only unique together.

My first table looks like this:

```
class Address(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Address'
    idx = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_code1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
    a_code2 = db.Column(db.Integer)
    property = db.relationship('Property', backref='Address', uselist=False, lazy='select')
```

And my second table looks like this (p_code1 + p_code2 are unique together - not separately)

```
class Property(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Property'
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('p_code1', 'p_code2', name='property_id'), )
    idx = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    p_code1 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Address.a_code1'))
    p_code2 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Address.a_code2'))
    addresse = db.relationship('Address', backref='Property', foreign_keys=[p_code1, p_code2], uselist=False, lazy='select')
```

The database initialises correctly, however, when I try to add something to the database, I get the following errors:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'Address' and 'Property'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.
```

...

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Address.property - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

Would anyone be able to identify what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `p_code1` and `p_code2` are unique together is not the problem here, but rather that you have two foreign keys in the same table `Property` pointing to `Address`, so sqlalchemy doesn't know how to map them.

I'm assuming that you need `p_code1 = a_code1` AND `p_code2 = a_code2` in order to map the relationship. I would do it explicitly setting the `primaryjoin` property:

```py
addresse = db.relationship(
    'Address',
    primaryjoin='Property.p_code1 == Address.a_code1 and Property.p_code2 == Address.a_code2',
    backref='property',
    uselist=False,
    lazy='select'
)
```

You don't need to define the relationship in Address if you use `backref`.

Comment: Amazing! Worked perfectly :-) Many thanks for your help!